# JpaRepository findBy field from referenced table

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpql

```
@Entity
@Table(name="seance")
@Data
public class Seance {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private Integer id;

    private java.time.LocalTime displayTime;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "seances")
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Repertoire> repertoires = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "reservationSeance", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Reservation> reservations = new ArrayList<>();

}


@Entity
@Table(name="reservation")
@Data
public class Reservation {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private Integer id;

    private java.time.LocalDate reservationDate;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_seance")
    private Seance reservationSeance;

   .........

}
```

I have two entities in relation ManyToOne, and I try extends JpaRepository

```
public interface ReservationRepository extends JpaRepository<Reservation,Integer> {
    List<Reservation> findReservationsByReservationSeance(Seance seance);
}
```

But as parametr i must use all Object Seance it is possible using JpaRepository find reservation only by id and displayTime from Seance Table or need to write own method?

Comment: Have you tried `...ByReservationSeanceIdAndReservationSeanceDisplayTime(Long, LocalTime)`?

Comment: If you need specific request, you can extend, or use derived request ; it's just an choice.

Comment: @crizzis ...ByReservationSeanceIdAndReservationSeanceDisplayTime(Long, LocalTime) Intellij does not show these fields as hints if i can use them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add your own query in your `ReservationRepository`

```
@Query("SELECT r FROM Reservation r WHERE r.reservationSeance.id=:seanceId AND r.reservationSeance.displayTime = :displayTime")
public List<Reservation> findReservations(@Param("seanceId") int seanceId, @Param("displayTime") LocalTime displayTime);
```

Comment: Why r.reservationSeance.displayTime > :displayTime not equal ?

Comment: i didn't know what you wanted exactly to do - do it as you prefer :) you can use `= > <` no matter what